# How to concisely prove that if a is bigger than one, then $(a \mid (b \mod a+c \mod a)) \equiv a \mid b+c$.

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $a \in \mathbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$, then the following proposition holds:

$a \mid [b {\pmod{a}}+c \pmod {a}] \iff a \mid b+c$.

I've been trying to prove it, but I am blocked. I tried using definitions, but I reached non conclusive results. I know that it's easy, but I need help.

thank you

Comment: The vertical bar and the $\equiv$ symbol are each verbs, so this sentence appears to have three verbs.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: I think it reads as follows:

a divides [ b modulo a + c modulo a] is congruent to a divides b + c  although i don't like the use of the parentheses in this so i may edit it.

Comment: That's how I read it too, @Ahmed, but I don't know how to parse a sentence with three verbs.

Comment: More generally, suppose $\rm b\equiv \bar{b}$ and $\rm c\equiv\bar{c}$ mod $\rm a$ for *any* integers $\rm b,\bar{b},c,\bar{c}$ (in particular, I assume you want e.g. "$b\pmod a$" to mean specifically the least residue of $\rm b$ modulo $\rm a$, but this specificity is unnecessary). Then we have an arithmetic congruence $\rm b+c\equiv\bar{b}+\bar{c}\bmod a$. So in particular $\rm b+c\equiv 0\iff \bar{b}+\bar{c}\equiv 0$, another way of phrasing this is $\rm a\mid (b+c)\iff a\mid (\bar{b}+\bar{c})$.

Comment: I am assuming my interpretation of your question is correct, though. You should endeavor to be clearer in the future. For instance, if you are using $\equiv$ for logical equivalence, this is a bad choice since it is also used to mean "congruent to" in modular arithmetic. It took me more effort to figure out what you were asking than to think of how to answer it (this is a pet peeve of mine).

Comment: aaah I think i see the issue with this

Comment: I'll keep in mind, it is customary for me due to my computer scientist formation, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $b\pmod{a}=b+ak$, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Similarly, $c\pmod a=c+aj$, for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Because $a|a(k+j)$, we have $a|(b+c)$ if and only if $a|(b+c)+a(k+j)$, which rearranges to $a| [b\pmod{a} + c\pmod{a}]$.